# Automatically set list item permission, after new item is created

Tags: sharepoint, wss

We have a SharePoint Team Site (WSS 3.0 not MOSS), that includes Tasks list to records every tasks related to a project. Here's the scenario.

Users :

- List item
- Supervisor1
- TeamMember1
- TeamMember2
- TeamMember3

How do we set the permission settings so that

- Every users (Supervisor and team members) can see any tasks.
- Supervisors can edit any tasks
- Team members can only edit their own tasks (tasks that were assigned to them, or created by them)

I was unable to achieve the intended results using standard WSS permission settings, without resorting to manual permission settings on each item in the list. I'm imagining that the automatic solution has to be accomplish using some sort of workflow or trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you do not need any workflow or event handlers** ( still you can use them for your purpos but they will slow down the performance if you will be having a lot of items)

go to setting --> list settings
click on Advanced Settings

in Item-level Permissions  in read access select all items
and in the same place in Edit access select only their own

and in permissions give list members a contributer role

for the suppervisor you can give him higher permission i think designer will work, or simply you can give him full controle on the list

Comment: Damm,.. When I was checking that features, I found out that users can click Edit link and I assumed that the users can do edit process. As it turns out, the users can enter Edit Mode, but cannot do any save. Thanks.

Comment: But in this case, it is not possible to edit task assigned to [Me], just the tasks I have created. Or is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set permissions by going to your List, click Settings dropdown.  Under Permissions and Management, click "Permissions for this List".  Click Actions and select Edit Permissions.  Select the User/Group you want the permission to be changed then Click Actions & select Edit User Permissions.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that inherits from SPItemEventReceiver and override the ItemAdded method, setting your custom permissions in the overriedden method using the API.

http://blogs.msdn.com/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to write an event handler or workflow that will run upon item creation which would look at these column values and set the item level permissions as such.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check this solution:  [SharePoint Column/View Permission by SharePointBoost (199$)](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/component/content/article/51-security/394)

Through this you can set read only permission to people you want on all the items, Your requirement "Every users (Supervisor and team members) can see any tasks" is solved!

Also you can set edit permission to Supervisors. Second trouble solved!

As Ali said, advanced permission>items level permission can fulfill your last requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a workflow to automatically assign permissions based on the user roles or [Assign To] fields.
Try the third-part tool [Permission Workflow](http://www.boostsolutions.com/permissionworkflow.html), this may help you to solve the issues.