# Override SPList.WriteSecurity behaviour?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.writesecurity.aspx) states, then WriteSecurity has 1 of 3 states possible:

- 1 — All users can modify all items.
- 2 — Users can modify only items that
  they create.
- 4 — Users cannot modify any list
  item.

But if I want behavour *nr. 2* plus *users can modify items that are assigned to them*?  Well if I grant a user full permissions (put in owners group) for list, then those can edit any item (not good). So why wouldn't it work by setting item level permission "full control" just for AssignedTo user (good)? I did, but that didn't help - access denied.

I want exactly the functionality as stated in question "[Automatically set list item permission, after new item is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142756/automatically-set-list-item-permission-after-new-item-is-created/145438#145438)", quoting:

> - Every users (Supervisor and team members) can see any tasks.
> - Supervisors can edit any tasks
> - Team members can only edit their own tasks (tasks that were assigned to them, or created by them)

but although answer has been accepted, the solution does not provide a way for users to edit items assigned to them *or* items created by user.

Help is appreciated, thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only way to do this is using Item-Based Permissions. E.g. have a Workflow or Event Handler change the permission on each file/object based on your requirements.

The solution you quote from the other task is simply setting `2` for `SPList.WriteSecurity` which still doesn't give users the possibility to edit something they have **not** created, but were assigned to - in this case you will need to give these users permission, e.g. by listening on the "Assigned To" field with an Event Handler (`OnItemUpdated`) and give the respective person the needed permission.
Furthermore the solution talks about just setting higher permissions for the users who should always be able to edit items (managers), which is a solution, but you do not have the granularity you usually want in situations like these.