# Program custom permission level

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

Can i program custom base permission level? There are many available in SPBasePermissions like

```
UseRemoteAPIs   Use SOAP, WebDAV, or Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007 interfaces to access the Web site. 
ViewFormPages   View forms, views, and application pages, and enumerate lists. 
ViewListItems   View items in lists, documents in document libraries, and view Web discussion comments.
```

However i want to make a custom one, something like:

EditItemsAssignedToMe + ViewItemsAssignedToMe + view/edit items i created.

Still finding my way out to [allow users view and edit items created by them or assigned to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848277/override-splist-writesecurity-behaviour).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OOTB you don't have the fine-grained control and can only assign a certain set of permissions as defined [on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287625.aspx) and [this blog article](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-4-SharePoint_2007__Fine_grained_permission_control.aspx).

However programmatically you can create a new SPRoleDefinition and assign it the appropriate permissions based on the SPBasePermissions enumeration as per [this blog article](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/02/creating-custom-permission-level-in.html). You might also want to read [this short guide](http://jamestsai.net/Blog/post/Understand-SharePoint-Permissions-Part-1-SPBasePermissions-in-Hex2c-Decimal-and-Binary-The-Basics.aspx) on the basics of SPBasePermissions.

If you want to go even further though and emulate the OOTB behaviour with your own custom permission set try [Implementing Custom Security Rights in SharePoint](http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/09/18/implementing-custom-security-rights-in-sharepoint/).

Comment: Yep, well, that's what i wanted to know. Custom Permission set.